# The antonym of "abling"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an antonym to the verb form of "able". If my English is correct, you can say the following:

> My large backpack is abling me to bring all my books to school.

(I see that a far better word in that circumstance would be "enables", but I'll let it stand.) However, is there a way to say something akin to the following?

> Arguably, this effect lessens as the obstacles get larger, as they now fill a larger part of the length of the passing wave, *unabling* the flow to onset hydro-elastic vibrations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for the antonym of a verb ***able*** that effectively doesn't exist in modern English.

Comment: Don't stand with *able*. Use *enable*.

Comment: *Enable* for the first usage, *disable* for the second; *able* and *unable* are not used as verbs in modern English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "*disable*" is to render completely inoperative, so that's not what you're looking for.

As general antonyms to "enable", you might like "***hinder***", "***hamper***" or synonyms for those you can find in a thesaurus.

But for your specific context of "anti-abling" a *flow* or *fluid*, by far the most common word is "***obstructing***" (which can be either partial, as rocks in a stream, or total, as a dam on a river).

From **ODO**:

> ***[obstruct](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/obstruct)***: *block (an opening, path, road, etc.); be or **get in the way of***

And **M-W**

> [***obstruct***](http://i.word.com/idictionary/obstruct): *to hinder from passage, action, or operation :  **impede, inhibit***

On the other hand, if a flow isn't impeded by objects within it, but rather by its own container (think a pipe with a ***bottleneck*** in it), the idiomatic word is "***constricted***".

**ODO**:

> [***constrict***:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/constrict) *to slow or stop the natural course or development of*

***TFD***:

> [***constrict***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=constrict) (v): *to make smaller or narrower by binding or squeezing.; To restrict the scope or freedom of; cramp*
>
> [***constrict***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/search.aspx?Word=&mob=1&tab=1) (n): *A constricted or narrow part.*

Comment: Yes, *obstructing* would be a good word in most fluid related scenarios. In this case, though, it's more the length scales involved that are specific. For now, I'll go with "inhibiting".

I see that my sentence as it stands now doesn't reflect this fully. The width of the pipe doesn't obstruct the flow, as there's ample room around it, but it's too long in relation to a passing pressure front.

Comment: @Tarjei In that case (too skinny for its length), the idiomatic word would be "***constrict***".

Comment: _Constrict_ seems to hit the spot, I'll go with that. Accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

The word is *enabling* (not * *abling* ) and the antonym would be *not enabling* / *hindering.*

However, in the given context, use *[impede](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/impede):*

> … as they now fill a larger part of the length of the passing wave, **impeding** the flow to onset hydro-elastic vibrations.

Comment: Impede was in my answer, Kris (and furthermore on OP's comment on my answer).

Comment: @DanBron And that **is** the word, not * *unabling.* In your answer, *impede* appears incidentally as one of the meanings of the word *obstruct,* not as a suggested answer by you, right?

Comment: If you're referring to the "unabling" in my answer, did you notice the scare quotes? That's how your "bogosity asterisk" is spelled in normal prose. If you believe "*the* word" ("***the*** word", really?) is impede, then you should, by rights, upvote my answer for providing it. That said, it turns out "*the* word" OP was looking for --- and chose explicitly over *impede* --- was "*constrict*".